# Realm Android "in" query sorting

Tags: android, realm

Using Realm for Android, I have a `String[] objectIds` of unique IDs for some Realm objects.  I'm trying to retrieve the corresponding Realm objects in the same order as the `String[] objectIds`.

```
String[] objectIds = new String[]{"1", "10", "2", "3"};
RealmResults<MyRealmObject> myRealmObjects = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).in("id", objectIds).findAll();

for(MyRealmObject obj: myRealmObjects) {
    log(obj.id)  //should print 1, 10, 2, 3
}
```

However, using .findAll() appears to re-order the results.  How can I retrieve a list of objects using "in" and get the same ordering as the objectIds array?  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

i.e. I want MyRealmObject.id == 1 to be the first result in the list, MyRealmObject.id == 10 to be the second result in the list, etc. (same as the objectIds array order).

Comment: What is the criteria for ordering?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I updated the question a little - I want the Realm results in the same order as the string IDs that are in the "objectIds" array.  So "MyRealmObject" with ID 1 is first, ID 10 is second, ID 2 is third, etc.

Comment: findAllSorted should work, right?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't think so.  I don't want to sort by ID, I want to sort based on the order of the IDs in the "objectIds" array...

Comment: Results are ordered only if you obtain them via `findAllSorted()` which sorts them by a specific field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to write a simple query to do what you want. The best alternative is to do something like:

```
String[] objectIds = new String[]{"1", "10", "2", "3"};
RealmResults<MyRealmObject> myRealmObjects = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).in("id", objectIds).findAll();
for (String id : objectIds) {
    MyRealmObject obj = myRealmObjects.where().equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    log(obj.id);
}
```

Of course, if you are certain that objects with the ids exist, you can simplify it a bit:

```
String[] objectIds = new String[]{"1", "10", "2", "3"};
for (String id : objectIds) {
    MyRealmObject obj = realm.where(MyRealmObject.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    log(obj.id);
}
```

Comment: I am already using the 2nd approach you mentioned as a workaround, I was hoping there was a simpler way to do it without looping using built-in Realm functions.  I'll mark this as the correct answer until something better comes along.

Comment: You are welcome to create an issue/feature request at https://github.com/realm/realm-java